# Doctrine: Cancel persisting of entity in event subscriber

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My ultimate goal is to prevent the user from editing an entity he has no write access to.

To achieve that, I've made an event subscriber for `prePersist` and `preRemove` events where I check access to the entity. If there is no access, I want to cancel the persistance or removal.

```
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    if (!$this->isTrackedEntity($args->getEntity())) {
        return;
    }

    if (...no access...) {
        // Cancel persist
        $args->getEntityManager()->detach($args->getEntity());
    }
}

public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    if (!$this->isTrackedEntity($args->getEntity())) {
        return;
    }

    if (...no access...) {
        // Cancel removal
        $args->getEntityManager()->detach($args->getEntity());
    }
}
```

This code seems to work for cancelling removals (although still not sure with what side-effects), but it doesn't work for cancelling persist.

Is there any better way to cancel the persist/remove of the entity, based on the business logic?

Comment: prePersist is called before the persist is actually performed so it is not surprising that your detach is not working.  I don't know of an event that would fit your workflow.  Traditionally you would of course check permissions before doing any operations.

Comment: Where would you check the permissions then? In my case, a lot of entities are being persisted indirectly as a Collection of another entity. So ideally those checks have to be on the entity level.

Comment: I think you should use voters to manage permissions in this case. This is not a job for Doctrine.

Comment: I would start by adjusting the UI to prevent the user from editing an entity in the first place.  Think how frustrating it would be for a user to see an option to update only to have it fail.  After that, I would use a voter (as previously suggested) to double check that the user has the correct permissions for the parent entity.  If a violation is encountered then, instead of trying to fix things by removing the sub-entity, I would simply cause the entire transaction to fail.